# failed to replace specific numeric character within string data in a column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe `'df'` that has many columns and one of these columns, `'Name'`, looks like the below:

```
Name
Alter0tive Medicine
A0lytics
Big Data A0lytics
Business A0lytics
Can0bis
Career Ma0gement
Chi0 Interne
```

Now as you can observe, `Name` columns has string data but these have zero `'0'` in place of the chatarcters `'na'` e.g. instead of `Alternative` it is `Alter0tive` and so forth.

I wanted to replace the '0' with 'na' so that I have proper strings.

What I am trying to do is:

```
df.Name = df.Name.str.contains(r'[0]').replace('0', 'na')
```

But this resulted in

```
Name
False
False
False
....
....
....
False
```

Why my code failed and how can I get the end result which should look like this:

```
Name
Alternative Medicine
Analytics
Big Data Analytics
Business Analytics
Cannabis
Career Management
China Internet
.....
.....
```

Comment: Use `df.Name = df.Name.replace('0', 'na', regex=True)`

Comment: No test `0` is necessary

Comment: Or `df.Name = df.Name.str.replace('0', 'na')`